# VirtualBox Guru Meditation error while entering protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox to emulate a x86 pc. I've written a bootloader which enters protected mode. But I always get a Guru Meditation error. Here's my code:

```
; clear interrupts
cli
; set up gdt
xor eax, eax
mov ax, ds
shl eax, 4
add eax, gdt
mov [gdtr + 2], eax
mov eax, gdt_end
sub eax, gdt
mov [gdtr], ax
lgdt [gdtr]
; enter protected mode
mov eax, cr0
or  al, 1
mov cr0, eax
; enter kernel
jmp 08h:0
```

I also tested jmp 0x2000:0000 but this didn't work too. What I'm doing wrong?

PS: Here's my GDT code:

```
; global descriptor table
gdt:
dq 0 ; null descriptor

; code descriptor kernel
dw 0x0000 ; base low word
dw 0x4000 ; limit low word
db 0x00   ; base high byte
db 0x40   ; flags
db 0x9A   ; access byte
db 0x02   ; base center byte

; data descriptor kernel
dw 0x0000 ; base low word
dw 0x4000 ; limit low word
db 0x00   ; base high byte
db 0x40   ; flags
db 0x92   ; access byte
db 0x02   ; base center byte
gdt_end:
```

Comment: Post complete code, we can't tell if your gdt is broken for example. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Jester added gdt code

Comment: @Jester it's hard to use a debugger when you are programming a bootloader...

Comment: @BlackBear if you are programming bootloader or OS, you are already expected to be able to use a debugger. It's not particularly difficult, since he is using a virtual machine :P Instead, he doesn't give us complete code and expects us to somehow guess the missing parts and debug it for him.

Comment: @Jester is this possible with the VirtualBox build-in debugger or do I need an external debugger?

Comment: No idea, it should be possible. The fields in your GDT entries are messed up, the order should be `limit low`, `base low`, `base center`, `access`, `flags`, `base high`.

Comment: @Jester thank you very much, I took the gdt entries from a tutorial, so I thought they are correct. But with your order it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience with CentOS-6.5 **Guru Meditation error** comes when your application requires more ram size then allocated ram size or CPU uses is more then 100% .
So increasing the allocated RAM size is one of the solutions for the Problem

Answer (score 0):

Close all running virtual machines, after that disable virtualization from bios. Then reboot. And then enable the virtualization from bios. Reboot. 
It worked for me